# what can make the system halt?

Tags: operating-system

There is an app (written in C++) running in the background for days in Linux, and if I send some signal to this app (using `kill -MYSIG`), asking the app to perform some defined operations, this might make my system not respond as it would normaly. By not responding normally, I mean after I send this signal to the app, the system shell (`bash`) cannot respond to any Linux commands (`ls,ps,top`...), just like when the system is down. If I wait a couple of minutes, the system comes back again.

I wonder what it is that causes the system to go down, or not to respond normally? Is it that the app uses too much CPU or memory? Then how does the system comes back?

Answer (score 1):

Linux scheduler has a state in which the process doesn't respond to signal(`TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` state),the signals sent to such a process stays queued untill process leaves the uninteruptible state, I guess thats the reason why u are not able kill/send signal to your app.If this is the case use `ps -A` and see if the state of ur app is D. If so then your app/process is in  TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE.

Probable The system doesn't respond because of the lack of available RAM. use `top` to see how much RAM/resources are consumed by your app, see `%CPU` and `%MEM` column. You can also Use system monitor tools (ex:Gkrell) to see system wide resource usage.You can lower your apps priority to reduce its resource consumption.

If your app has read/write/select socket calls you should use strace/coredump  to see where is it that your app is spending  most of its time.this usually happens If select is in a tight loop or your app performed a blocking system call like read/write on socket

Comment: Well, the problem is that I was able to send the `kill` signal and the app was able to receive it, but after this, the system cannot make any response to any command I typed in, including `ps,top,ls`...

Comment: Run top first and then start ur app, I think it will let you know if ur app is consuming too much of memory/resources. Also run gdb and see what happens after sending the signal. A strace of your app will reveal all the system calls made by your app and I guess the time spent in each of those. Probably that will help you in understanding the reason for slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving your app a lower priority, unless it is already the lowest priority and still causes problems.

[Lowering priority in Linux](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/)

Comment: If the app owns not the lowest priority, then how could that make the system not respond to my shell commands?

Comment: It might make it easier for others to give more specific replies if you post the section of code that runs when it receives a kill signal. Is any data being written during this time, for example?